# compile clisp source code in aarch64 docker container

Tags: docker, common-lisp, arm64, clisp

I want to compile clisp source code **before compiling xindy** in Ubuntu16.04 aarch64 docker container(which started in aarch64 server).
The gcc is:

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The OS information is:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

When I run the commands below

```
cd clisp-clisp_2_49_60-2017-06-25
./configure --ignore-absence-of-libsigsegv
cd src
make
```

the error shows that:

```
    ./comment5 arilev1e.d | ./gctrigger | ./varbrace > arilev1e.c
    ./comment5 arilev1i.d | ./gctrigger | ./varbrace > arilev1i.c
    ./comment5 genclisph.d | ./gctrigger | ./varbrace > genclisph.c
    ./comment5 noreadline.d | ./gctrigger | ./varbrace > noreadline.c
    ./comment5 lispbibl.d | sed -e '/^%% /
    {s///;p;d;}
    
    ' -e '/^#line /!s/.*//' > gen.lispbibl.c
    gcc -I/mnt/clisp-clisp_2_49_60-2017-06-25/src/gllib -g -O2 -W -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wmissing-declarations -Wimplicit -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-format-nonliteral -O2 -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -DENABLE_UNICODE -DDYNAMIC_MODULES -I. -c spvw.c
    In file included from spvw.d:23:0:
    lispbibl.d:3953:4: error: #error varobject_alignment depends on CPU – readjust varobject_alignment!!
    #error varobject_alignment depends on CPU – readjust varobject_alignment!!
    ^
    lispbibl.d:7111:60: error: 'varobject_alignment' undeclared here (not in a function)
    typedef int subr_size_check[1 - 2 * (int)(sizeof(subr_t) % varobject_alignment)];
    ^
    In file included from spvw.d:998:0:
    spvw_garcol.d:1382:4: error: #error Unknown value for 'varobject_alignment'!
    #error Unknown value for 'varobject_alignment'!
    ^
    spvw_garcol.d: In function 'gc_sweep2_varobject_page':
    spvw_garcol.d:1396:9: error: 'uintVLA' undeclared (first use in this function)
    (uintVLA)p2 = (uintVLA)p1; \
    ^
    spvw_garcol.d:1430:6: note: in expansion of macro 'move_aligned_p1_p2'
    move_aligned_p1_p2(count); /* relocate and advance */
    ^
    spvw_garcol.d:1396:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    (uintVLA)p2 = (uintVLA)p1; \
    ^
    spvw_garcol.d:1430:6: note: in expansion of macro 'move_aligned_p1_p2'
    move_aligned_p1_p2(count); /* relocate and advance */
    ^
    spvw_garcol.d:1396:17: error: expected expression before ')' token
    (uintVLA)p2 = (uintVLA)p1; \
    ^
    spvw_garcol.d:1430:6: note: in expansion of macro 'move_aligned_p1_p2'
    move_aligned_p1_p2(count); /* relocate and advance */
    ^
    spvw_garcol.d:1396:17: error: expected expression before ')' token
    (uintVLA)p2 = (uintVLA)p1; \
    ^
    spvw_garcol.d:1490:2: note: in expansion of macro 'move_aligned_p1_p2'
    move_aligned_p1_p2(count); /* relocate and advance */
    ^
    spvw.d: In function 'getSP':
    spvw.d:1115:10: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
    return &dummy;
    ^
    spvw.d: At top level:
    spvw.d:1346:23: warning: no previous declaration for 'error_pseudocode_alignment' [-Wmissing-declarations]
    global _Noreturn void error_pseudocode_alignment (uintP address, const char* prefix, const char* name) {
    ^
    In file included from spvw.d:954:0:
```

How could I do to compile clisp source code(clisp-clisp_2_49_60-2017-06-25) in a aarch64 docker container?

Comment: Docker images comes with very minimal packages. Do you have a specific requirement to compile soruce code other than installing `sudo apt-get install clisp`?

Comment: There is no clisp in the source, so I have to compile source code.

Comment: please check https://www.devmanuals.net/install/ubuntu/ubuntu-16-04-LTS-Xenial-Xerus/how-to-install-clisp.html

Comment: Maybe x86_64 Ubuntu16.04 can install clisp directly.
But in my arm64 Ubuntu16.04, I can't find clisp after run "apt update"
root@localhost:/mnt/xindy-2.5.1# apt search clisp
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you have with clisp_2_49_60-2017-06-25 is fixed in clisp 2.49.92 (from 2018-02-18).

You can download it from https://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/clisp/.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I install clisp and some dependency debs from https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-arm64/2/ .Thank you all the same.

Comment: This fixed my issue compiling clisp 2.49 from source on debian where running make check resulted in "undefined function SAVEINITMEM" and sporadic segfaults. Downloading and building clisp 2.49.92 cleared the make check, and no problems yet. Thanks!